# Parse Cloud Code DoesNotMatchKey

Tags: node.js, parse-server

My schema:

```
Match: 

scheduledBy (Pointer to user) 

scheduledWith (Pointer to user)



Photo: 

owner (Pointer to user)
```

I want to find photos for users that do not have any matches.

What I tried:

```
    let photoQuery = new Parse.Query(MODEL.Photo.className());
    photoQuery.include('owner');

    // Do not include people who have matches
    let matchQuery = new Parse.Query(MODEL.Match.className());
    photoQuery.doesNotMatchKeyInQuery('owner', 'scheduledBy',   matchQuery);
    photoQuery.doesNotMatchKeyInQuery('owner', 'scheduledWith', matchQuery);

    // Get final results
    return photoQuery.find()
```

This only works for the scheduledBy column.

Seems like you can't do doesNotMatchKeyInQuery with the same key and query but different query keys for some odd reason.

Can anyone confirm this? If so what would be the best alternative?

I removed scheduledBy and used scheduledWith only and that worked as well.  So it's not something wrong with the data it's a bug with Parse I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track, but I think the problem is the use of a single inner query to qualify two fields on the main query.  This is more of a hunch, but I think you'll get the result you seek with...

```
// use a distinct instance of an inner query for each test in the outer query
let matchQueryBy = new Parse.Query(MODEL.Match.className());
let matchQueryWith = new Parse.Query(MODEL.Match.className());

photoQuery.doesNotMatchKeyInQuery('owner', 'scheduledBy',   matchQueryBy);
photoQuery.doesNotMatchKeyInQuery('owner', 'scheduledWith', matchQueryWith);
```